# Databinding a checkbox in windowsphone

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I would like to make my application on windowsphone remember that I have checked a checkbox the next time it starts. How can I do that by Databinding or MVVM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `View/XAML` you will have a `CheckBox`

When you `check/uncheck` value you are basically playing with `IsChecked` property of `Checkbox`

In the `ViewModel` create a property let's say `IsChecked` and bind the value of checkbox's checked property like this. This property will be bound to Checkbox in View or in other words CheckBox's IsChecked property will be set using this property

```
<CheckBox IsChecked={Binding path=IsChecked}/>
```

**Based On Comment**

You will put code above in XAML which is View in MVVM terms and in the ViewModel you will create a Property like this

```
public bool IsChecked
{
    get
    {
        return yourBoolVariableContainingPropertyValue;
    }
    set
    {
         //load value from last checked/unchcked value
         yourBoolVariableContainingPropertyValue = value;
    }
}
```

I would suggest you to follow some basic tutorials like [Creating your first MVVM silverlight application on windows phone 7.](http://www.labo-dotnet.com/post/Creating-your-first-MVVM-silverlight-application-on-windows-phone-7.aspx)

Comment: Okay I udnerstand the code.. but how to create a property in the view model?